# How to force include a field into AuthComponent's user?

Tags: authorization, cakephp-3.0

I have a `role` field for my users that I really need to access. If a user is an `admin`, they would have extra available actions on many of my views.

So, in the `beforeRender` of my `AppController` I do this:

```
$this->set('loggedInUser', $this->Auth->user());
```

This way, I can use `$loggedInUser` to access the logged in user in all of my views.

The thing is that from the 10 fields that the table `users` has, the `AuthComponent` seems to fetch only these 4: `id`, `username`, `verified` and `modified`.

I cannot find anywhere in my code specifying those 4 fields as a whole.

What is causing `AuthComponent` to select randomly those specific fields? How can I force the fields I need?

**Extra information in case it is needed**:

All the fields of the `users` table are:

```
id
username
email
password
role
verification_hash
email_md5
verified
created
modified
```

The initialization of `AuthComponent` inside my `AppController` is the following:

```
$this->loadComponent(
    'Auth',
    [
        'authorize' => 'Controller',
        'authError' => 'You are not allowed to go there',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'email' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: That is not correct, by default AuthComponent will fetch all fields. Also, in the `fields` key of your configuration the `email` key is not required.

Comment: @JoséLorenzo, thanks, do you know what causes AuthComponent to fetch only those specific fields?

Comment: Do you have anything in `$_hiddenFields` in your entity?

Comment: The `User` entity contains the `$_accessible` variable and the `_setPassword` function for password hashing.

Comment: how did you implement the login function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the accessible fields in my entity. I had left there some non-existent fields that I had forgotten to remove.

For some reason it seems that the AuthComponent did not like those non-existent fields and it fetched only 4 fields.

Removing from the accessible fields the ones that did not exist seems to fix the problem.